# Get aspectJ working on a constructor in spring 2.5

Tags: spring, aspectj

Is it possible to get aspectj - aop ot ltw variants - executing on a constructor in spring 2.5?

I understand that spring 3 allows this behaviour, sadly i'm stuck with 2.5 for now.

If anybody has any code for either aop or ltw to work on an autowired business bean's constructor in spring, I would be v. grateful.

Comment: What if you move your logic from the constructor to method with @PostConstruct and intercept that method...

Comment: @Evgeny I don't have that option, i'm trying to weave into a library file